# Hyperlinks of README.md not working in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, github-flavored-markdown

I am working on a project that is being collaborated in [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) and tried to write the documentation using [Github](https://github.com/) flavored markdown language. I added hyperlinks in following fashion. I learned it from the `README.md` of [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async)

````
### Functions
* [`tableList`](#tableList)

<a name="tableList"/>

### tableList ( callback )

Lists all the tables in connected database.


___Arguments___

* `callback`[Function] : Callback function

___Example___

```js
db_wrapper.tableList( function( err, response ){
    // Do something.
});
```
````

But in this way hyperlink is not appearing. What is the problem? Is the markdown syntax of Gitlab different from Github? My `README.md` file is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8128234/). And it appears like the image below.

[image: Hyperlink appearance]

Comment: Maybe,you just need to wrap a new line.
if you want to input 'text text text [title](link) text text',you need to input like: text text text
------there is a new line------
[title](link)
------there is a new line------
text text text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Github](http://www.github.com) the syntax to add hyperlink is following -
`[Text](#section_name)`. But Gitlab doesn't support the same syntax. I don't know if it is a bug or something. In Gitlab hyperlinks need to be added just like the links. You need to give the full url, like following - 
`[Text](full url of the section)`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first link, make sure to leave an empty line after the title:

```
### Functions

* [`tableList`](#tableList)
```

The [`caolan/async/README.md`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caolan/async/master/README.md) contains links:

```
## Documentation

### Collections

* [`each`](#each)
* [`eachSeries`](#eachSeries)
```

With target sections as:

```
<a name="each" />
### each(arr, iterator, callback
```

You need to add the name of the anchor just before the sections that your links are referencing.

Note that there should be, since GitLab 6.6 (February 2014) anchors added automatically for any section of a markdown document.
See [commit 61748c9](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/61748c993de8a38300c0c038cec5a07e6c324cd6#diff-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e) and [Pull Request 6219](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/6219) and [suggestion 4533114](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/4533114-anchor-for-titles-in-markdown-files-and-wiki).

Comment: Still not working. I have added the source file and how it is appearing in gitlab in the question. Would you please take a look again?

Comment: @taufique did you try removing the empty line between the name of the anchor (that I have added in my edited answer) and the section itself, just to see if that makes any difference?

Comment: @taufique also, what version of GitLab are you using?

Comment: version is 6.9.2. Yes, I did, but it's making no difference.

Comment: @taufique do you see the little section icon which is supposed to be added for each sections since GitLab 6.6? (https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/61748c993de8a38300c0c038cec5a07e6c324cd6/app/assets/images/icon-link.png)

Comment: Yes, the icons are there.

Comment: I found something. The link address my browser is showing when I hover over the hyperlink item and the `chain` icon is different. Actual link is `hostname/gitlab/repo-name/...#sth`, but in the hyperlink it is `hostname/repo-name/...#sth` isn't it a problem?

Comment: @taufique it is indeed.

Comment: @taufique could you try and add the right url in ```[`tableList`](#tableList)```? like `/gitlab/repo-name/...#sth`: ie an absolute path.

Comment: Full url? With or without quote? An example would have helped.

Comment: @taufique Not full url, only the part after `http://localhost/xxx`: the `/xxx` part, just to force an absolute url to be generated and see if that works better. Replace `/xxx` by the link which is working (the one associated with the section icon)

Comment: No it's not working. Gitlab is not forcing anything. It is appending whatever it finds in the parenthesis. Seems like it is a bug of gitlab.

Comment: @taufique but if you put in the parenthesis the link which is working (the one you see when hovering on the section icon), it should be working since "Gitlab is appending whatever it finds in the parenthesis".

Comment: I am getting `http://host/xxx/blob/master/gitlab/xxx/tree/master#connect` instead of `http://host/gitlab/xxx/tree/master#connect`.

Comment: @taufique and is `http://host/gitlab/xxx/tree/master#connect` the link that is working.

Comment: @taufique so an internal link like ```[`tableList`](/gitlab/xxx/tree/master#connect)``` wouldn't work?

Comment: @taufique a bug indeed. One to report to report to GitLab.

Comment: But sadness is I don't know how to report bugs.